In what paper did Dijkstra say "with your hands in your pockets"?
I'm looking for a paper by Edsger Dijkstra (which I've read before) in which he talks about a certain mathematical argument that I can't quite remember what it was, but it was an elementary strategy to perhaps fill up a checkerboard or something.  Right now it makes me feel that perhaps that argument was solving the problem of tiling a $2^n$ by $2^n$ courtyard with a statute in the middle (occupying one square)---but I don't remember what it was, so I can't be sure.  Instead of talking about a statue, I think he talked about removing a square from the checkerboard.  Also, I don't recall that proof being by induction.
What I remember is that he said something to the effect of

Don't worry. This is the type of mathematics that you can do "with your hands in your pockets".

I'm putting in quotes only the words that I would more firmly believe we would in the paper.  For instance, instead of "type of mathematics", he could've said "kind of mathematics".  But I have to even put my more firm belief in check because search engines are not revealing this paper to me using these keywords.
I also remember that it was an EWD-paper and it was perhaps not a late one because I believe I was reading them all in chronological order and I did not get too far.  (But it's possible I would have read a late one out of order for some reason.)
What paper was it?

The second google hit I get for “dijkstra hands in pockets” is https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD10xx/EWD1036.html .

Thank you!  How did I go wrong?  I insisted that I was recalling correctly the passage "with your hands in your pockets", but those were not the right words and I never really tried less keywords.  Thanks!
